# Springboot Webclient log request body using netty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am trying to use Netty HttpClient to log request and responses but, When I try to configure the http client I am not able to import the package netty.transport.

```
return HttpClient.create().wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient",
                LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);
```

Build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

When I try to insert

```
import reactor.netty.transport.logging.AdvancedByteBufFormat;
```

I am getting the error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'transport'
```

I am not sure why my IDE is unable to fetch this library. I am using Intellij idea